# ASP.NET MVC 2 Validation Error Styles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble with my ASP.NET MVC 2 form validation and setting my style.

Here is an example of my form, with a validation error:

[image]

The field uses the following html:

```
<div class="registration-field">
     <label>FullName</label><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FullName) %>
     <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FullName)%>
</div>
```

The problem is, to show the highlight across the entire element, I need to add the CSS class "registration-field-error" to the first div.

```
<div class="registration-field registration-field-error">
     <label>FullName</label><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FullName) %>
     <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FullName)%>
</div>
```

The CSS for registration-field-error is:

```
.registration-field-error
{
    background-image:url(../Content/Images/box-background-error.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y; 
}
```

I can do some complicated logic to check the ViewState for errors, which works fine for server validation errors, but not for client-side validation:

```
<% if (ViewData.ModelState["FullName"] == null) { %>
     <div class="registration-field">
<% }  else { %>
     <div class="registration-field registration-field-error">
<% } %>
```

My first thought was to make a new Html helper to decide if it should use the registration-field-error class:

```
<%= Html.FormFieldFor(x => x.FullName, ViewData.ModelState) %>
```

And then editing the MicrosoftMvc.Ajax.js script to add the class when it detects clientside validation errors.

Or, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First wrap your div elements without any conditional logic but wrap your Validation Messages in span with class name "error" like below:

```
<div class="registration-field">      
  <label>FullName</label><%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FullName) %>      
    <span class="error"><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FullName)%></span>
</div>
```

and then use a function given below to dynamically add the error classes:

```
$(function(){
 $("div span.error").each(function(){
  var className = $(this).parent().attr("class") + "-error";
  if($(this).html().length > 1)
   $(this).parent().addClass(className);
 });
});
```

This would be changing less parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I think there's a typo above though, with the line if ($(this).html().length < 1). I think it should be length > 1?

Comment: If you're using client-side validation, you should update this. Must be easy - probably, the easiest way is to execute nearly the same code each X miliseconds + add the code removing `registration-field-error` class when validation error class is removed from child `div` / `span`.